# Image Cropper flexible rectangle like tiny scanner IOS

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to crop image selected in rectangle, the rectangle should be like in tiny scanner app of iOS

http://a5.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Purple2/v4/ed/90/3c/ed903cee-1929-e65f-ed57-f073bbea60ad/screen568x568.jpeg

Any links to the similar kind of source code ?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Photup](https://github.com/chrisbanes/photup).
It is open-source project and has functionality that you need.

See this class: https://github.com/chrisbanes/photup/blob/master/client/src/uk/co/senab/photup/CropImageActivity.java

Comment: where is cropper in this application ??? 

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=uk.co.senab.photup

Comment: @Bhaskar when you upload a photo, you can crop it.

Comment: @Bhaskar see https://github.com/chrisbanes/photup/blob/master/client/src/uk/co/senab/photup/CropImageActivity.java

Answer (score 0):

i always found this very helpful, [Cropper Library](https://github.com/edmodo/cropper)

check it out.